# Tracking thread initialization in source with large applications

Tags: java, multithreading, debugging

If an application starts many threads ( using `new Thread()` as well as using `ExecutorService` ) at various places in its code ( including from within the referenced jars ) , then what is the best way to identify the source code that started any specific thread ( as seen in an executing instance of the application )

This is helpful , for example , in case a thread causes an `Exception` - and we need to start at the source code where the thread was initialized ( so that the context is clear ).The thread dump I get from VisualVM shows many running/waiting threads but the stack root always seem to be `at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)` - not very helpful.
`

Comment: What about giving them all unique names?

Comment: @Andremoniy this is an excellent idea! But what if this is legacy code?

Comment: many of the thread names are generated in code - not helpful for debugging

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to insert code at the points that the threads are being created?  If so, then create a static HashMap in your main class along with a public static put method.  Then whenever you create a thread t1, call Main.putThreadId(t1.getId(), "some text that identifies the method that's creating the thread"), and when you catch an exception look up the value in the HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is that, set [Thread.uncaughtExceptionhandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) to every thread you start.
It has a method called:

```
uncaughtException(Thread t,Throwable e)
```

Inside this you can put a log or something with which you can later identify from where this code is called for. But of-course for every thread, you will have to specify individually as the origin.

You can set a global one by `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(myHandler);`. But to make it distinct, probably have a ThreadGroup or something.

Though all this isn't helpful if the thread is started by referenced Jar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the map approach given before, but instead of some text, you generate a new `Exception` at the point where you create the thread. Put this exception as value in the map. You can later get the stack trace if you need. For `Executor`s, you can hide this in the `ThreadFactory` creating the worker threads.

This problem occurs in similar fashion when using `Runnable`s. Sometimes you want to know where the `Runnable` has been created and queued, on top of any stack trace starting at the `run` method.

Of course the whole *legacy code* and *referenced jar* problem is: you want to solve a problem that needs coding, but without coding. Not easy :)